# Python count() with print()

Tags: python

While doing simple `print` found one issue:

```
>>> print("123456".count(""))                                   
7
```

Why it print 7 instead of 6?

Comment: Try `print("1".count(""))` See the two empty spaces? now try `print("11".count(""))`